Weasis permissions (to access external media) in Ubuntu 24.04LTS
I use Weasis Dicom viewer (from Snap Store) to view medical DICOM files.
On Ubuntu 20.04LTS and 22.04LTS, in the Snap Store page, once downloaded, there's a button for changing Permissions.

This opens a menu and the last option allows you to toggle on / off accessing removable storage devices.

I can't find a similar option in 24.04LTS - there's a button with three dots next to the title bar, but that only gives me the option to uninstall.
How can I select permissions (specifically to access removable storage devices) in 24.04LTS?
If this is something that's set by the producers of the software let me know by comment and I'll contact them but if it can be changed from within Snap Store or other setting in Ubuntu I'd be very grateful for help - I may be missing something obvious!
I'm pretty sure this isn't a standard permissions issue as I'm running the software as a standard user, and as the same user can access the relevant folders either via GUI (Files) or navigate there in a terminal.
I need to use this as I have the files in an encrypted partition which Weasis is treating as a removable storage device. I know the files themselves are readable by Weasis because if I copy the files to my /home (for example) folder, Weasis can access them. If they are in the encrypted partition, Weasis doesn't see the partition at all. The partition is in /media - but when I navigate there within Weasis to open a file, it doesn't show anything in /media.
Thank you.

In 24.04 you go to Settings and Apps to enable permissions.

@amar - thank you - so simple! Please feel free to pop that as an answer, I'm happy to accept. Thanks again.

I have done so :)

Ubuntu 24.04 has a lot of changes and one of them is the way snap applications are handled.
Before you had to configure your snaps from Snapstore. It caused a few unnecessary mouse clicks and also you had to be connected to internet.
Now you manage your snap applications directly from Settings, Apps, (your snap). The picture below is for Firefox:

